# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Can't figure out how to set up reaction roles (part 2)

Tags: python, discord.py

I asked a question about reaction roles earlier, that problem got solved but now I have another problem. Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  message_id = payload.message_id
  if message_id == 800172672860291132:
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
    
    role = None
    if payload.emoji.name == '':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Red')
    elif payload.emoji.name == '':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Orange')
    elif payload.emoji.name == '':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Yellow')
      
    if role is not None:
      member = payload.member
      if member is not None:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        print("done")
      else:
        print("Member not found")
    
    else:
      print("Role not found")


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
  message_id = payload.message_id
  if message_id == 800172672860291132:
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
    
    role = None
    if payload.emoji.name == '':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Red')
    elif payload.emoji.name == '':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Orange')
    elif payload.emoji.name == '':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Yellow')
    
    if role is not None:
      member = payload.member
      if member is not None:
        await member.remove_roles(role)
        print("done")
      else:
        print("Member not found")
    
    else:
      print("Role not found")
```

The bot hands out roles just fine, but when a reaction is removed, it does not remove the role & says "Member not found". If you look at my code you'll see that means Member is still None. And like I said, the part that gives roles is working fine. Not sure what to do, any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to read [the docs on the reaction event payload](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent), it says that the member value is only available if event_type is REACTION_ADD.

As to how to solve your problem, you can use the *on_reaction_remove(reaction, user)* which has the user as a value.

As backup for cache-issues you could keep a list of members that have the role and check the reactions for the missing member when you get the *on_raw_reaction_remove(payload)* event

Comment: Okay, so on the parts where I have if `payload.emoji.name` would I just replace _payload_ with _reaction_?

Comment: @CarterMichaelis `reaction.name`

Answer (score 2):

`on_raw_reaction_remove` does not give you a member object the same way `on_raw_reaction_add` does. However they both have one thing in common, [`user_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.user_id). Find your member through `payload.user_id`

Code as used on my testing bot:

```py
@client.vent
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 800172672860291132:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
        
        role = None
        if payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Red')
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Orange')
        elif payload.emoji.name == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Yellow')
        
        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("Member not found") 
        else:
            print("Role not found")
```

Comment: Hmm this still gives me "Member not found"

Comment: @CarterMichaelis I've added the code as I used it on my testing bot. Try copying it directly from there. It is working fine on my bot

Comment: Yeah I dunno, I copied + pasted the code, still isn't working

Comment: @CarterMichaelis Just for the sake of trying, can you do `member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)` ? does that help you find the member?

Comment: @CarterMichaelis Let's break it down to something simpler. Remove or comment out everything you have under `on_raw_reaction_remove`. Then do only `payload.guild_id`, `payload.user_id`, `client.get_guild(guild_id)`, `guild.get_member(user_id)` and print all these elements to see what says in the terminal. If you are positive that `on_raw_reaction_add` is working and giving roles, then I don't think it can be an intents thing